# I get errors including "apache config test fails, aborting" when trying to create a subdomain. What do I do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, apache-http-server

I just made a change to the httpd.conf file. The reason I did this is I'm trying to set up a subdomain. I now would like to restart apache2, but when I try to restart I run into a slew of errors. Specifically I added the changes that are found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203580/creating-subdomains-in-amazon-ec2 to the httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@subdomain.example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/subdomain

  <Directory /var/www/example.com/subdomain>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/subdomain.example.com.error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/subdomain.example.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

but when I try to restart apache I get the following errors.

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/xxx.com/subdomain] does not exist
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at /xxx/xxx/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:193
AH00014: Configuration check failed
apache config test fails, aborting
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/xxxcom/subdomain] does not exist
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:193
AH00014: Configuration check failed
apache config test fails, aborting
```

so lets break down these errors

1. `AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/xxx.com/subdomain] does not exist (2)No such file or 
   directory:`
   to fix this do I add a file /var/www/xxx.com/subdomain if so should it be empty or have stuff in
   it. If it should have stuff in there what type of stuff?
2. `AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at

   /xxx/xxx/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:193`
     I don't know what this means or what to do about it.
3. `AH00014: Configuration check failed apache config test fails, aborting`
   I'm not sure what to do here either.
4. `AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at 
   /xxx/xxx/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:193`
   Do I do the same thing ans error AH00112

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the directories that are missing are created. These directories should have appropriate permissions as well. Usually 755 permissions are sufficient.

Exmaple as below.

```
mkdir /var/www/example.com/subdomain
mkdir /var/log/apache2
```

Replace example.com and subdomain with actual directory names.